# RS485 serial Communication

Tags: linux, serial-communication, rs485

I have two embedded machines(same manufacture). I have connected two machines through 2 wire Rs485 serial communication. I wired like this (machine1-pin Tx+ to machine2- pin Tx+ and machine1- pin Tx- to machine2- pin Tx-). I have tested data transmission on minicom tool. In that one machine1 only transmitting data and other machine2 as receiver. how can make it acts as machine1 as receiver and machine2 as transmitter? Baud rate:9600, No h/w & s/w flow control, Xon/off-None.

Comment: The connection is bi-directional, where is your problem?

Comment: i can't able to receive data on machine1

Comment: Broken cable? Wrong settings? Does it work with other cables/machines? What have you tried so far?